# onChange Event not Triggered in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, onchange

```
export default function ActionRolesPage(props) {
      const [authorities, setAuthorities] = useState([]);
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      let list = [];
      useEffect(() => {
        getAuthorities();
      }, []);
      const getAuthorities = () => {
        doGetAllAuthorities()
          .then((res) => {
            getValidatedData(res.data, "array").map((data) => (
              list.push({ authority: data})
            ))
            setAuthorities(list);
          }).catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
          })
      }
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        const { name, checked } = e.target
        console.log(name,checked);
        let tempUser = authorities.map((user) => (
          user.authority === name ? { ...user, isChecked: checked } : user
        ));
        setAuthorities(tempUser);
      }
    
      if(authorities.length){
        console.log(authorities);
      }
    
      
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading....</div>}>
            <div className="page-content">
              <MetaTags>
                <title>Add Role | IG One</title>
              </MetaTags>
              <Container fluid>
                <Breadcrumb
                  title="Add Role"
                  breadcrumbItems={[{ title: "Settings" }, { title: "Roles" }, { title: "Add" }]}
                />
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <Card>
                    <CardBody>
                      <Row className="mb-3">
                        <label
                          htmlFor="example-text-input"
                          className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                        >
                          Name
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-8 mx-0">
                          <Input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="text"
                            name="name"
                            required
                            value={name}
                            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                            placeholder="Name Of User "
                          />
                        </div>
                      </Row>
                      <br></br>
                      <br></br>
                      <Row className="mb-3">
                        <CardTitle>
                          Authorities
                        </CardTitle>
                        <div className="col-md-2">
    
                          {
                           
                              authorities.map((data,index) => (
                                <>
                                  <div key={index} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                                    <div className='col-md-10 mx-0 mt-2'>
                                      <Input type={"checkbox"}
                                        checked={data?.isChecked || false}
                                        name={data.authority}
                                        onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
                                        className="form-control"
                                        style={{ cursor: "pointer", paddingLeft: "1rem" }}
                                      /></div>
                                    <div>
                                      <label style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} htmlFor={data.authority} className="col-md-50 col-form-label"> {data.authority}</label>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </>
                              )) 
                          }
                        </div>
                      </Row>
                      <Row className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-4">
                        <Button color="dark" type='submit' className="btn-xs" style={{ width: "40%", cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                          Add Role
                        </Button>
                      </Row>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Form>
              </Container>
            </div>
          </Suspense>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
```

Here is the whole code. I want to handle multiple checkboxes but onChange Event not triggered. There is a function handleChange it calls when onChange triggered but in my case there is no error seen in console as well as not display any event at console please resolve my doubt.

I also need to update the form getting respose from backend is checked authority name array How to handle checked state in checkbox.

Comment: Do you have the code of the Input Component?

Comment: Yes I add the whole Code

Comment: I don't see `handleChange` being used in the code. Maybe use it?

Comment: Yes I use it at onChange. but onChange not triggered at my console

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a custom component for **input**, pass your onChange handler as prop and call inside the component as onChage event of  `<input>` field. Or if you used any third-party lib, then you just need to pass a callback as prop. Otherwise Try this: `<input>` instead of `<Input`>

```
<input type={"checkbox"}
       checked={data?.isChecked || false}
       name={data.authority}
       onChange={(e) => console.log(e)}
       className="form-control"
       style={{ cursor: "pointer", paddingLeft: "1rem" }}
     />
```

Comment: Not work sir :(

Comment: any error or warning? in my case it's working fine.

Comment: Sir I add the whole code please check my mistake where I am wrong

Comment: Have you made <Input> a custom component? or it is a HTML input ?

Comment: Yes <Input> is a custom component but I change to <input> but nothing happens

Comment: can you provide the code for the custom <Input> component?

Comment: The <Input> component taken from reactstrap

Comment: I checked your code locally on my pc, all is good, I can see SyntheticBaseEvent  logged in my console.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/BnPJQOejJnXJ have a look, i have atteched screenshoot